# MKUserTrackingButton does nothing on tap

Tags: swift, mkmapview, ios11

I implemented the sample from WWDC 2017 with MKUserTrackingButton, and it successfully appears, but always is showing progress animation on click. What does it mean, who knows?

p.s. Location permission is asked, sample from WWDC working fine, connection is fine, rotation is endless.

[image]

Comment: Can I see your location setting? https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDs9V.png

Comment: Kosuke, thank you, it appears the answer

Answer (score 1):

The reason was "Never" in settings.

[image]

Apparently I set it during recurring uninstalling and rebuilding the app.Thanks Kosuke Ogawa, the screenshot is him.

p.s. Anyway I'd prefer to get something from MKUserTrackingButton, not just endless rotation. Hope Apple will change this behavior.